# In Django, how can I avoid cascade deletions when using a GenericRelation?

Tags: django

According to the [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#s-reverse-generic-relations), if I add a `GenericRelation` to my model, then when an instance of that model is deleted, it will cascade-delete anything with a `GenericForeignKey` pointing to it.

I need the querying benefits of having a `GenericRelation`, but I do NOT want it cascade-deleting stuff (I can't believe potentially-catestrophic behavior is what the django people selected as the default...).

Both the `GenericRelation` class and the `GenericForeignKey` class do not accept an `on_delete` param for customizing the behavior.  Is there a way I can avoid the cascade deletion?  The docs suggest possibly using the `pre_delete` signal, but the docs for that are skimpy so it's unclear how that can help me...

Answer (score 0):

You can override the model's delete method:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
    # Handle the GenericRelation field
    related_objects = self.my_generic_relation.all()
    for obj in related_objects:
        # Add custom logic to unlink rather than delete
        # e.g., obj.my_generic_foreign_key_field = None
        # obj.save()
    super(MyModel, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

So you can prevent the other models deletion by changing their related model (reassigning the children to another parent), or leaving the related id field empty (children become orphans)